# Getting and index out of a dictionary<vector3,node>.values

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine

Working with C# in Unity3d.

I made an dictionary and now I want to return a value from that dictionary not by its key but by its index, how can I do this?

```
return _nodeDictionary.Values[i];
```

That line give me this error:

error CS0021: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary.ValueCollection'

Comment: What do you mean by "not by its key but by its index"? The key is the index in a dictionary.

Comment: Aah,, i see. Gues that awnsers my question then.

Comment: Correction: as @Sprunth mentioned in his answer, a dictionary is unordered so you cannot access it by index. What I meant was, in order to look something up in the dictionary, you use the key to do it so that is your index. But you can't access it with a numeric index like you would for an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the dictionary directly, you cannot access by index as a dictionary is unordered.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx):

> For purposes of enumeration, each item in the dictionary is treated as a KeyValuePair structure representing a value and its key. The order in which the items are returned is undefined.

If you really need to access by index, you can use

```
return _nodeDictionary.Values.ToList()[i];
```

Note that this generates a temporary list! You should consider changing your data structure as this defeats the purpose of a dictionary. Moreover, since the list has an undefined order, index i could mean anything. You would have to search the list (or dictionary) anyway.

Comment: Yes, thanks! That clears it up. I decided to also create a normal array with the same data as the dictionary.values so i can refer to that when I need it, that is cheaper that converting it to a list every time.